# Casting error Cannot convert type to System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

Im trying to update a joining table with Entity Framework but I am not getting far as I am getting a casting error:

> *Cannot convert type to System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection*

So when I try to pass a Passenger Object to a Flight entity it cannot make the cast.

Here is the table structure:

```
Flight table - FlightID PK
Passenger Table - Passenger ID PK
Passenger_Flight table - PassengerID PK,FlightID PK


        if (isValid())
        {
            Passenger cpass = ((Passenger)passengerIDComboBox.SelectedItem);

            Flight newflight = new Flight { 

                Rego = planeRegoComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                DepartureTime = departureDateTimePicker.Value,
                ArrivalTime = arrivalDateTimePicker.Value,
                DepartureLocation = departureLocationComboBox.GetItemText(departureLocationComboBox.SelectedItem),
                ArrivalLocation = arrivalLocationComboBox.GetItemText(arrivalLocationComboBox.SelectedItem),

                Passengers = cpass // this is the problem. Cannot convert type to System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection

        };
            flightEntity.Flights.AddObject(newflight);

            Validate();
            //flightEntity.Passengers.AddObject(pass);
            flightEntity.SaveChanges();
            refreshItems();

        }
```

Thanks in advance. I hope I have supplied enough information. This question is linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087747/an-object-with-a-temporary-entitykey-value-cannot-be-attached-to-an-object-cont

Comment: If Passengers is a collection shouldn't you create the `newFlight` first and then do `newFlight.Passengers.Add(cpass)`? Otherwise how you want to assign a single passenger to a collection of passengers?

Comment: Hi and Thanks. newFlight.Passengers.Add(cpass)gives me the following error:
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
I believe Passengers is an Entity reference Collection. So adding an Passenger object then creates the relationship in the joining table. Please correct me if this isn't the correct terminology.

Comment: If the entity is already tracked try `.Attach`

Comment: no luck. Error message is: Attach is not a valid operation when the source object associated with this related end is in an added, deleted or detached state. Objects loaded using the No Tracking merge option are always detaached

Comment: Then it seems tha cpass is already tracked by a different context. An entity cannot be tracked by more than one context at the same time.

Comment: Yes that makes sense,thanks. How do I change context and keep the relationship between the Flight and the Passenger?

Comment: You probably would have to `.Detach` the entity from the old context and `.Attach` to the new one.